# Comparison method violates its general contract! Exception from google map sdk

Tags: android

A new Exception after upgrade target API to 31

compileVersion = 31
targetVersion = 31

com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.0

Any ideas?

```
Fatal Exception: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
Comparison method violates its general contract!
java.util.ComparableTimSort.mergeHi (ComparableTimSort.java:870)
java.util.ComparableTimSort.mergeAt (ComparableTimSort.java:487)
java.util.ComparableTimSort.mergeCollapse (ComparableTimSort.java:413)
java.util.ComparableTimSort.sort (ComparableTimSort.java:213)
java.util.Arrays.sort (Arrays.java:1305)
java.util.Arrays.sort (Arrays.java:1488)
java.util.ArrayList.sort (ArrayList.java:1470)
java.util.Collections.sort (Collections.java:206)
java.util.Collections.sort (Collections.java:159)
com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.vector.v.s (v.java:4)
com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.vector.bq.b (bq.java:151)
com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.gmm6.vector.at.run (at.java:48)
```

throw from google sdk and have no idea about it.

Comment: Always check for latest version: https://developers.google.com/android/guides/setup and see if changing to the latest version fixes the problem.

Comment: I'm experiencing same issue (mergeLow as well as mergeHi), lots of crash reports in Firebase Crashlytics. Since there are much older versions affected with same issue, it has nothing to do with changes of target SDK version. I found at least a few reports with targetSdkVersion = 30, also Crashlytics indicates, that issue affects much older app versions with targetSdkVersion=28 (no reports, since they are limited to last 90 days). It's clearly Google Play Services update issue, something like that happened before couple of times